# SAP UI5 [Panel]- How to create a new Panel on button click

Tags: sapui5, rendering, panel

I have a requirement where I have add the panel on click on a button.

In the controller function I have written the code like below. I don't get the error in console neither do I get the panel when I click the button.

However when I `console.log` the panel object I can see the panel is created but not sure why not reflected in the view. suggestions please.

```
onAddObjectiveClick: function () {
        var panel = new Panel({
            headerText: "Description",
            visible: true,
            backgroundDesign: "Solid",
            content: new TextArea({
                value: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry",
                growing: true,
                width: "100%",
                height: "263px"
            })              
        });
```

}
`this.getView().addDependent(panel);` // at this place I have tried `setExapanded` and `setExpandible` function too but none helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically creating an object, assigning to a local variable and not adding it to your view.

You should have any kind of container element with an aggregation to add your Panel.

Depending on the container the *aggregation* name will be different and thus the method you need to call in order to add the Panel to it.

Example: If you need to add this Panel inside the aggregation `content` of the `sap.m.Page` class, you should

1) Have the Page

2) Capture it inside the controller

3) call the `addContent()`